# installing windows service error: cannot open service control manager on computer. this operation might require other privileges

Tags: windows-services, installutil

i have windows 8 
i have a windows application wrtitten with c# and on visual studio 2013 and want to install this application.

i open command prompt write:

```
c:\..\instalutil.exe c:\projectfolder\filename.exe
```

after i run this code it give me the error :

```
An exception occured during the Install phase.
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '.'. This operation might require other privileges.
The inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with the following error message: Access is denied.
```

This is my computer i dont know why it needs access right? and i dont know how to give right privilege.

also i changed my sercviceProcessInstaller Account property to LocalSystem and also tried with LocalService but both of them gives me the same error.

what should i do to give right privilege?

Answer (score 30):

I found the answer finally:

> The solution: RUN COMMAND PROMPT AS ADMINISTRATOR

Comment: Hi I have The same problem I Run this commond : `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe  E:\DataService\DataSrvice.exe` It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem myself, in my case, since I couldn't run "Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio" explicitly from .exe file as administrator and create a shortcut to run it inside the Visual Studio using "Tools => External Tools". 
To work around  the issue, I tried running Visual Studio as Administrator and it worked as well.

It seemed that it was the Visual Studio program that hadn't required access to perform the operations.